# Ajax using Prototype.js in OFBiz

Tags: ajax, prototypejs, ofbiz

I need to make an Ajax call inside OFBiz framework using `prototype.js`. I am doing that from a `.ftl` file. I am confused about how to handle the server side - through Java event or Java service? What is the best practice? And also I am having problems making the framework recognize the `prototype.js` file. There is some issue with the path name in the script tag. It has to be some peculiar naming as per OFBiz framework standards.

I searched Google but I only found links on how to use prototype but none on the combination of prototype + OFBiz. If anybody has done anything in OFBiz like this, please help.

Answer (score 0):

The server process the AJAX request just like any other request. It may contain an event or not, and the response your js function will get is the HTML output ( if the response is a view ). If you want to use JSON, you must create an event with `type="jsonservice"` ( and you must include the jsonservice handler in your controller file ). This way you can send and receive data structures using AJAX.